# How to update google map circle through ajax in Gmaps4rails 1.5.6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3.2, gmaps4rails

In my rails application I am using gmaps4rails gem with 1.5.6 version. I want to update my map circle attributes through ajax

Can any one please suggest me a procedure to do this?

Answer (score 1):

First, get your circle, should be in `Gmaps.map.circles`

Then:

```
 circle.serviceObject.setRadius(number)
```

Answer (score 1):

In the success function of ajax, you can code like this:

```
 Gmaps.loadMaps()
 // if you are using markers
 markers_json = JSON.parse(markers) 
 Gmaps.map.replaceMarkers(markers_json)
 // if you are using circle
 Gmaps.map.clear_circles() 
 circle_json = JSON.parse(circle)
 Gmaps.map.circles = circle_json
 Gmaps.map.create_circles()
```

Thanks